# how to parse C# generic collection list in typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, razor, generic-collections

This is my .cshtml code,

```
  @ { var myList = (List<MyViewModel>)ViewBag.MyCollection; }
    <input id="myListHidden" type="hidden" data-my-list="@myList" />
```

And this is my typescript code to get the value above,

```
     let _myList = $('#myListHidden').data('my-list');
```

And this is the return value,

```
      "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.Data.ViewModels.MyViewModel]"
```

I just want to iterate through this collection. This is what I've tried

```
     for (let entry of _myList ) {
         console.log(entry);
       }
```

But it gives the output as `System.Collections.Generic.List` as string.
I want to iterate all the values inside this collection.

**Edit**

MyViewModel's properties are as follow,

```
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but this will help --> https://forums.asp.net/t/1999070.aspx?Pass+2+Lists+to+a+View

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, your reference link is just to iterate collection inside `Razor` code. what I want is inside `Typescript`

Comment: `console.log(_myList)` ?

Comment: @StevenSann, you need to create the same class for `MyViewModel` in typescript also and then map you Generic Lit in c# with Array of class in typescript.

Comment: @er-shoaib, I've edit my question , you can take reference for my ViewModel.
Can you give me sample code to create class for this , and how can I map inside Typescript ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to serialize your collection and then output that serialized value as "Raw" (or else the razor engine will escape your JSON, and you don't want that)

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@{
   var myList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.MyColection);
}

<input id="myListHidden" type="hidden" data-my-list="@Html.Raw(myList)" />
```

In this example, I use the Newtonsoft serializer.  You can use it by installing the NuGet package.

The above will generate something like this:

```
<input id="myListHidden" type="text" data-my-list="[{"Id":1,"Name":"Bob","Active":true}]" />
```

You can then use the value how you wish

**EDIT:**

Note that if you do not use `@Html.Raw()` the razor engine will output this:

```
<input id="myListHidden" type="text" data-my-list="[{&quot;Id&quot;:1,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Bob&quot;,&quot;Active&quot;:true}]" />
```

Comment: got it , additionally , what's the different between with or without using `@Html.Raw` ??

Comment: i updated my answer with an example of what the output would look like without @Html.Raw